# Combinatorica and MultiplicationTable in Mathematica 11

Tags: combinatorics, algebra, group-theory, combinatorica

I try to use

```
<<Combinatorica`
```

or call

```
IntervalSlider; Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

or call

```
Quiet[Needs["Combinatorica`"], General::compat]
```

in Mathematica 11, but it fails to obtain the FiniteGroupData for DihedralGroup:

```
FiniteGroupData["DihedralGroup[4]", "MultiplicationTable"] // Grid
```

It shows error messages:
[image]

The relevant information here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/DihedralGroup.html

See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124877/warning-in-version-11-0-when-loading-package-combinatorica). But I tried to use the functions mentioned but it does not work.

Are there some ways to fix them?

Comment: It turns out that 

FiniteGroupData[{"DihedralGroup", 4}, "MultiplicationTable"] // Grid

works. But not the other ones.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FiniteGroupData.html is part of the built in group theory functionality, see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GroupTheory.html. It is independent of the old Combinatorica package.